# Windows 10 is 2 minutes behind even though the time is synchronized with time.windows.com

Tags: windows-10, time

Windows 10 is 2 minutes behind even though the time is synchronized with time.windows.com. What could the issue be?

Screenshot of the current settings:

[image]

Even though it says that some error happened, it seems to have synchronized one hour ago (2019-06-23 at 9:54 PM), but still the displayed time is two minutes behind.

I use Microsoft Windows 18.09 "Professional".

Comment: Are you on a Server when time is controlled by a group policy?  Non-domain machines should show the correct time. If a domain machine, you need to ask the domain administrator.

Comment: @John no~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Perhaps run the basic repair steps to see if this corrects time. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run first:  dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   then SFC /SCANNOW .  Restart when the above is complete and test.